# How to display category children only?

Tags: categories, nesting

I'm making a web store with Exp-resso Store and want to have a product category listing on the left side of the web page. The categories are nested four levels. I want the user to click a category to reveal the sub categories. Then the user has to click again to reveal the sub categories of the sub category. Is this even possible with EE?

As an alternate solution, I'm thinking using JS to do everything client side. The upside here is that it's much faster for the categories to reveal/load. (I want to have the first level listed on a separate menu on the top of the website. Is it possible to only list level 2|3|4?)

But if it is possible to do easily with EE I'd love to know it for later use.

EDIT: I've looked at this: http://420creative.com/blog/entry/showing-child-categories-based-on-hierarchy-in-expression-engine But this isn't easier than making everything work with JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin like Child Categories may help you with this:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/child-categories